# Number all rows in table based on order of another column value

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a table which has 497k words. Each word and their relative frequency in the English language is a row. I'd like to make another column which will order them from 1 to 497k (the number of words in this list) based on their frequency, with the highest frequency to be 1 and so on. How can I do this? I am using MySQL 5.1.54

Comment: you can start writing a query, and we will help you fix it and improve it

Comment: What is the purpose of this when you can place an `ORDER BY` within your retrieval statements?

Comment: -1 simple count(B) followed by an order by.

Comment: @MattWestlake: If it's so simple for you, could you post a more complete solution as an answer instead of downvoting the question? I'd like to see how you would do this in a simple way without using variables or a O(n^2) self-join.

Comment: @MarkByers was working on it when abhshkdz posted it.

Answer (score 1):

I come up with this (complicated, but maybe fast) one-statement solution:

```
update vocabulary SET rank = 

(
SELECT ranking.rank FROM (
  SELECT @rownum:=@rownum + 1 as rank, voca.word
  FROM 
      (
        SELECT v.word, v.frequency
        FROM vocabulary v
        ORDER BY v.frequency DESC
      ) voca,
     (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
) ranking
WHERE ranking.word = vocabulary.word
);
```

I am sure this can be optimzed further but it may be a good starting point to have a one-statement solution for this.

Furthermore this may still have issues with ranking rows with different word but same frequency.

Here is a SQL Fiddle for it:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a00e2/1

Comment: That looks great! I have never see sqlfiddle before either. I will try this asap. Ty

Comment: It didn't work :/. I forgot to mention that the same word can occur multiple times. A unique entry in the database consists of a word and a PoS tag. I was messing around with your code but cant get it to pull out the PoS tag. Any help?

Comment: Just updated the code for it. `update COCA_wordlist SET rank = 

(
SELECT ranking.rank FROM 
(
  SELECT @rownum:=@rownum + 1 as rank, voca.word, voca.PoS
  FROM (SELECT v.word, v.freq,v.PoS FROM COCA_wordlist v ORDER BY v.freq DESC) voca,(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
) ranking
WHERE ranking.word = COCA_wordlist.word AND COCA_wordlist.PoS = ranking.PoS
);`